# How to write code for generating checksum for paytm initiate transaction api

Tags: c#, api, integration, paytm

How I should pass the values in this function
Paytm.Checksum.generateSignature(paytmParams, PayTmMKey)

I want to hit initiate transaction api after generating checksum.
what more values should I add for initiate transaction api.

This is how paytm doc says to implement checksum.

```
/* initialize an array */
Dictionary<string, string> paytmParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

/* add parameters in Array */
paytmParams.Add("MID", "YOUR_MID_HERE");
paytmParams.Add("ORDER_ID", "YOUR_ORDER_ID_HERE");

/**
* Generate checksum by parameters we have
* Find your Merchant Key in your Paytm Dashboard at https://dashboard.paytm.com/next/apikeys 
*/
String paytmChecksum = Paytm.Checksum.generateSignature(paytmParams, "YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY");
Response.Write("generateSignature Returns: " + paytmChecksum);
```

Link to it-https://developer.paytm.com/docs/checksum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we will make json string(json_for_checksum) for Initiate transaction api request and will pass this in generateCheckSumByJson function

string json_for_checksum = "{"requestType":"Payment","mid":"" + MID + "","orderId":"" + order_id + "","websiteName":"" + Website + "","txnAmount":{"value":"" + Amount + "","currency":"INR"},"userInfo":{"custId":"WE25622"}}";

string Check = paytm.CheckSum.generateCheckSumByJson(Merchant_key, json_for_checksum);

Assuming you know your basic parameters in json string and download paytm dll

Answer (score 0):

For initiate transaction API checksum should be generated from body of json string. Please refer the below code.
For more detail you can also use Java code under Initiate transaction API.

```
/* import checksum generation utility */
import com.paytm.pg.merchant.*;

/* initialize JSON String */
String body = "{"\mid\":"\YOUR_MID_HERE\","\orderId\":"\YOUR_ORDER_ID_HERE\"}";

/**
 * Generate checksum by parameters we have in body
 * Find your Merchant Key in your Paytm Dashboard at https://dashboard.paytm.com/next/apikeys
 */

paytmChecksum = PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(body, "YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY");
System.out.println("generateSignature Returns: " + paytmChecksum);
```